# zsh extended globbing to create sub directories

Tags: zsh

```
% zsh --version
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0)

% ls -l 
bootstrap/    local_folder/ ssh_confs/    zsh_confs/
```

I am trying to create a sub directory called "files" inside all the directories in my current folder.. I want to use zsh globbing features..

```
% setopt extendedglob

% mkdir -pv */files   
zsh: no matches found: */files

% mkdir -pv **/files
zsh: no matches found: **/files
```

Answer (score 0):

Globbing is for *pattern matching* not for *pattern generation*: It only returns a list of existing files that match the pattern, not a list of every name that could match the pattern.

`*/files` just means "any **existing** entity named 'files' in any directory in current working directory".

You *can* use globbing to get a list of the directories (and only the directories) in the current working directory by using the `/` *globbing qualifier:

```
ls -ld *(/)
```

In order to create the 'files' subdirectory in every one of them you could use a `for`-loop:

```
for directory in *(/); do mkdir "$directory/files"; done
```